# How to make `find` output full absolute file names?

Tags: find

When I run `find`, it outputs relative (`./`-based) file names, but I need full absolute (`/`-based) names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should call `find` with absolute directories' names, for example:

```
find "$PWD"/ -iname '*.txt'
```

Comment: I'd advise quoting `"$PWD"` just in case.

Comment: @jw013: oh, right.

Answer (score 0):

@enzotib's answer is probably better but I use

```
find "`pwd`" -iname '*.txt'
```

because the lowercase letters and ` are easier for me to type.

Comment: Even so you should quote that: `"\`pwd\`"`. Try it: `mkdir '/tmp/foo bar' && cd !#:1 && find \`pwd\`; rmdir !#:1`.